# Angular: Select displaying incorrect default value when two objects have same value

Tags: angular

**Goal**: Get the dropdown default value to be Primo if the individual is a Male Cousin and Prima if they are a Female Cousin

**Problem**: If I just have the condition for Male Cousin it shows Primo, but as soon as I add Prima to the array, it defaults to that instead

**Background**: 
Because Spanish has multiple genders for some words that in English only have 1 word:
They both have the same value, but different view values:

relationships = [

{value: Cousin, viewValue: Primo },

{value: Cousin, viewValue: Prima }
]

Database value for relationship for this individual = 'Cousin'

**What I've tried**:

- **I noticed that if two items in the array have the same value, it selects whichever one is first in the array. Since I have them sorted in alphabetical order, it displays Prima no matter what.**

  - Changing it from mat-select to mat-option or vice versa doesnt help
  - I went back and reviewed information on data binding and reactive
    forms
  - I tried changing the order that items are added to the array
  - The only thing that sort of worked was to put Primo BEFORE Prima even though that is NOT in alphabetical order.

Is it possible to do what I want but still have two objects with the same value?

Below is a minimal example of my code:

**HTML**:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Relationship" formControlName="relationship" required>
         <mat-option *ngFor="let rel of relations" [value]="rel.value" (click)="selectRelationship(rel.value)">
            {{ rel.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**TypeScript**:

```
let relationship = this.individual.Relationship; //comes from Database. Value is 'Cousin'

this.relations = [          
            { value: 'Cousin', viewValue: 'Cousin' },
            { value: 'Daughter', viewValue: 'Daughter },            
            { value: 'Other (Write in Box Below)', viewValue: 'Other (Write in Box Below)' }
        ];

this.form = this.fb.group({
            'firstName': [this.individual.FirstName],
            'lastName': [this.individual.LastName],
            'relationship': [relationship],
            'other': [this.individual.OtherRelationship]
        });

this.indexCousin = this.relations.map((o) => o.value).indexOf("Cousin");

if (this.individual.Relationship.startsWith('Cousin')) {
    if (this.individual.Gender == 'M') {
        this.relations[indexCousin].viewValue = "Primo";
        this.relations.push({ value: 'Cousin', viewValue: "Prima" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting and getting value as string or int.. you can use the whole object which makes value unique regardless of *value* attribute. Let me know if you needed more details...

> HTML

```
<mat-select placeholder="Relationship" formControlName="relationship" [(value)]="selected" required>
         <mat-option *ngFor="let rel of relations" [value]="rel">
            {{ rel.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

> TS

```
public selected: Relation;
//Set value
this.selected = this.relations[1];
//Get selected value
let relation = this.selected
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thank you, I like this idea. I set it equal to the object. Question I have is, it did not work until I set mat-option to [value]="rel" *instead of* [value]="rel.value. I didnt understand this as I thought it was value on mat-select that mattered for default, not mat-option. ALSO, the Database value is no longer updating after I made this change.

Comment: The reason  it did not work with `rel.value` is because `rel.value` is repeated.. so Angular chooses selected as the one defined first in the list (not alphabetically).. but `rel` is unique because while it has repeated `value` but different `viewValue`.. For the database bit.. try to console.log payload and make sure that you pass `rel.value` not `rel` to server. If you pass `rel`, database call will fail. You may need to do some payload formatting before uploading to server.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused by this last statement. In HTML you show to do value=rel. But in the last comment you said to do rel.value to the server. Yes, looking at the debugger it tries to send the entire object with value and viewValue. It seems like this solution solves one problem but creates another?